# Silence only status output after checkout

Tags: git, githooks, git-checkout

I want to provide my own custom coloured git status via a `post-checkout` hook.

How can I disable the default monochrome short status output that is displayed after checking out a branch?

I only want to disable the status part (so I don't print it twice), but I want to keep other messsages such as:

```
Already on 'master'
```

---

Alternatively, if there's no way of only disabling the short status output, is there a way to force all `checkout`s to be `--quiet`?

I want to avoid double status outputs under all circumstances.

Comment: Short answer: no, you must supply the `-q` flag, which you can't do with an alias. You can use the "override `git` to check subcommand" trick (then invoke `command git checkout -q "$@"`), or of course an alias like `git co` = `checkout -q`. (It might be nice if all Git commands had a systematic "default options" configuration item, instead of randomly added things like `log.decorate`, but they don't.)